# Spring Data JPA multitenancy - defining multiple tenants for one resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose we have Spring boot app with multitenant architecture (Shared Database and Shared Schema).

I want users to have access only to data they own. Spring offers solution using CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver and @TenantId annotation. Such solution works well as long as every entity contains some column tenant_id annotated with @TenantId.

The problem is that in my app there is a possibility that one entity should be accessible by multiple users (and it means, multiple tenants also).

**Is there any approach to define multiple tenants for one entity?**
If multitenant architecture is not designed for such problem, are there any alternatives/design patterns etc.?

I've tried to just annotate List of tenants with @TenantId, but Spring decides to ignore this annotation and behave as if it wasn't even defined.

```
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Tenant> tenants;

    @TenantId
    public List<UUID> getAllTenants() {
        return tenants.stream().map(Tenant::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
}
```

Resolver method implementation (there is also interceptor saving tenant-id value in TenantContext):

```
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(TenantContext.getCurrent()).orElse(new UUID(0,0).toString());
    }
```

In such scenario Spring does not perform this "multitenancy data isolation" - everything is accessible for every user. I expected that only tenants returned by method getAllTenants() will be permitted to access data. When I annotate single field (for example UUID tenantId) everything works well.

Comment: It isn't Spring that offers the `@TenantId` etc. but HIbernate that is adding that support and what you want isn't supported by this. You can write your own using Hibernate filters and a bit of AOP.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and for your answer. I'm not really sure how can I achieve it with your approach - I have found some resources: https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/17/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part5/ but it doesn't look perfect - requires load time weaving (I would prefer stay with only spring AOP) and writing own queries for findById methods. Do you have any examples?

Comment: It doesn't require loadtime weaving depending on the pointcut, you can write one that executes the aspect for all `@Service` methods, which would work perfectly well with the default AOP mode. It will indeed only work with queries as soon as you use `entityManager.find(id, Entity.class);` the filters don't apply.

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite confused. I thought the idea is to create pointcut on openSession() method to intercept and modify Session object setting the tenantId. What would I do if I wrote an aspect for my @Service method? Should I get current session via SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and set this tenantId? Is this what you mean? And do you see any workaround for fetching object without writing those queries for every repository?

Comment: That is exactly what you should do and no writing your own query is the only workaround (Unless you want to re-write the parts  from HIbernate that do `entityManager.find`).

Comment: Looking at your question are you sure you want to store 1 entity for multiple entities? Feels like you are leaking data from one tenant to another. Shouldn't each entity just have one tenant to begin with (which is also the assumption and basis of the hibernate tenant support).

Comment: Definitely I don't want to dig into EntityManager method, as there is high probability of implementing it incorrectly. The reason I want share data between tenants is because I have some hierarchical tenant structure and tenants above should access their "children tenants" data. If I have an opportunity to talk with someone experienced in this topic, could you please also explain what CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver#validateExistingCurrentSessions method does? I find official doc explanation hard to understand. In such described architecture, what should be the return value?

Comment: Make sure to post answer to question if you want so I can mark it as the accepted one :)

Comment: I have no idea what that does, you need to talk to someone who knows the internals of HIbernate for that (although I have seen too much of that as well). If you want to have a parent to see its childs records, then why does it need to be atteched? You can have a leveling in there, which would still allow 1 record for 1 tenant but still you can use the parent to obtain the childs data. You could introduce a hierarchy for that, which you probably need to store somewhere. You could, based on the hierarchy, write your own tenant strategy to implement this.

Comment: It doesn't need to be attached, it was just one idea of solving this problem. Unfortunatelly, I have no idea what do you mean by "writing own tenant strategy". I had to reject Hibernate filters approach because i'm not satisfied with this direct fetch problem. Using Hibernate mechanism with CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, at the end of the day I have to provide exactly one tenantId in resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier method. If I do it as described, everyone can read their data, but parent can't see children one. No idea how to achieve leveling if I dont know what entity will be requested.

Comment: Okay, I think I know everything I needed. Thank you for all your help. I've noticed that also using this basic mechanism with @TenantId does not work when you call repo.findById(id) what is quite unexpected for me. I've decided to implement my feature using JPA entity lifecycle callbacks and I hope I will not be surprised by Hibernate once again. That will be probably the most flexible way to achieve my goal.